How to disable scheduled automatic sleep on macOS Sonoma with M1 chip?
Since the Sonoma OS update, the sleep schedule interface in the system setting has been removed.
But the actual last scheduled sleep is still present and I can't seem to remove it.
Every night at 10pm, a window pops up that says:

This computer has been schedule to go to sleep automatically. If you do nothing this computer will go to sleep automatically in 2 minutes.

How can I kill this scheduled automatic sleep via the terminal ?

Execute pmset -g schedule to see what is set (just for info purposes.)
Then execute pmset schedule cancel to remove all settings.
Also pmset repeat cancel to remove any repeat pmset commands.
Then execute pmset -g schedule to make sure the setting has been canceled.
